# How are math instructions implemented on hardware?

Tags: math, optimization, compiler-construction, cpu

I'm looking for some sample code that "emulates" the most frequently used math instructions(addition,subtraction,multiplication,division) and will cover all steps that a hardware based cpu processor follows.

The first thing i did was to use google and got this :
https://bochs.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/bochs/trunk/bochs/cpu/

But its not what i want.This is an instruction wrapper/emulator while i want to see how the cpu does everything down to bit level...

..

Comment: read about NAND gates and how they are used to implement these basic instructions

Comment: compile some example code and let the compiler output a mixed c/asm list file. Then, inspect the result :)

Comment: The problem is that i want to see what the actual instruction does behind the scenes...

Answer (score 2):

[TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) is a great way to get introduced to digital logic. If you search Google for something like "TTL arithmetic", you'll probably get lots of links to tutorials about how to create things like adders and multipliers.

(Of course knowing what to search for is half the problem.)

Comment: I have a test board that i still haven't even unpacked :o so i would like to see some software implementation first

Comment: It's actually a lot easier to do this sort of thing in hardware than it is to "simulate" it in software.

Answer (score 1):

You should Google for *two's complement arithmetic*.

This [Computer Arithmetic Algorithms Simulator](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/simulator/) may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want 'code that "emulates",' (in its literal terms) you'll need a parser for Boolean Algebra grammar:

```
S ::= E;
E ::= (E)
E ::= T AND T
E ::= T OR T
E ::= T NOR T
T ::= NOT T
T ::= IDENTIFIER # Set of named bits
...
Include grammar for STATEMENTs.
```

Simply, write a parser for the above grammar so that you can start writing code in Boolean Algebra.

```
# Half Adder
SUM = A NOR B;
CARRY = A AND B;
```

Edit: I realize that this SO question already defines a solution. [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c)

---

From here, you can build an Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) in the von Neumann Architecture that should be able to handle of the aforementioned arithmetic: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/ALU

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on the arithmetic logic unit (ALU)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) has a number of links which might be useful to you. Among them articles about [addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29), [multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_ALU) and [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28electronics%29).