# parsing boolean expressions with boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I am trying to write a parser for boolean expressions using boost spirit. I found a great example here on stackoverflow.com, [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c), that helped me a lot understanding how the spirit grammars and the parsing process work.

The code compiles and runs perfectly on my dev machine which is a debian 6 box with 2.6.32-5 bigmem kernel and boost 1.42 (spirit 2.2) installed. I decided to modify the code for my purposes in order to parse not only expressions in the form of: "a and b or c" but also expressions of the form "sc[100] and cc[200] or fd[300]", where the operands of the boolean operation also need to be parsed in order to get an ast as i need it for my project. I chose the following approach:

- add another abstract data type

  ```
  struct op_or  {};
  struct op_and {};
  struct op_xor {};
  struct op_not {};
  struct r_sc  {};

  typedef std::string var;
  template <typename tag> struct binop;
  template <typename tag> struct unop;
  template <typename tag> struct rule;

  typedef boost::variant<
          var,
          boost::recursive_wrapper<unop<op_not>>,
          boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and>>,
          boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_xor>>,
          boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or>>,
          boost::recursive_wrapper<rule<r_sc>> > expr;

  template <typename tag> struct rule
  {
      explicit rule( const expr& lhs, const expr& rhs )
          :   oper1( lhs ),
              oper2( rhs )
      {

      }

      expr oper1, oper2;
  };



  template <typename tag> struct binop
  {
      explicit binop( const expr& lhs, const expr& rhs )
          :   oper1( lhs ),
              oper2( rhs )
      {

      }

      expr oper1, oper2;
  };



  template <typename tag> struct unop
  {
      explicit unop( const expr& rhs )
          :   oper1( rhs )
      {

      }

      expr oper1;
  };
  ```
- modify the visitor for printing the ast

  ```
  struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void>
  {
      printer( std::ostream& outputStream )
          :   _outputStream( outputStream )
      {

      }

      std::ostream& _outputStream;

      //
      void operator()( const var& variable ) const
      {
          _outputStream << variable;
      }

      void operator()( const binop<op_and>& binaryOp ) const
      {
           printOp( " & ", binaryOp.oper1, binaryOp.oper2 );
      }

      void operator()( const binop<op_or>& binaryOp ) const
      { 
          printOp( " | ", binaryOp.oper1, binaryOp.oper2 );
      }

      void operator()( const binop<op_xor>& binaryOp ) const
      {
          printOp( " ^ ", binaryOp.oper1, binaryOp.oper2 );
      }

  void printOp( const std::string& operation, const expr& lhs, const expr& rhs ) const
  {
      _outputStream << "(";
          boost::apply_visitor( *this, lhs );
          _outputStream << operation;
          boost::apply_visitor( *this, rhs );
      _outputStream << ")";
  }

  void operator()( const unop<op_not>& uaryOp ) const
  {
      _outputStream << "(";
      _outputStream << "!";
          boost::apply_visitor( *this, uaryOp.oper1 );
      _outputStream << ")";
  }

  void operator()( const rule<r_sc>& rule ) const
  {
      printRule( " serviceCode ", rule.oper1, rule.oper2 );
  }

  void printRule( const std::string& rule, const expr& lhs, const expr& rhs ) const
  {
      _outputStream << "{";
          boost::apply_visitor( *this, lhs );
          _outputStream << rule;
          boost::apply_visitor( *this, rhs );
      _outputStream << "}";
  }
  };
  ```
- modify the grammar rules for generating also rule objects

  ```
  template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
  struct parser : qi::grammar<It, expr(), Skipper>
  {
      parser()
          : parser::base_type( _expr )
      {
          using namespace qi;
          using boost::spirit::ascii::string;

          _expr  = _or.alias();

          _or = ( _xor >> "or" >> _or )[ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_or> >( _1, _2 ) ] |
              _xor   [ _val = _1 ];

          _xor = ( _and >> "xor" >> _xor )[ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_xor> >( _1, _2 ) ] |
              _and[ _val = _1 ];

          _and = ( _not >> "and" >> _and )[ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_and> >( _1, _2 ) ] |
              _not[ _val = _1 ];

          _not = ( "not" > _base )[ _val = phx::construct<unop<op_not> >( _1 ) ] |
              _base[ _val = _1 ];

          _base = ( ( '(' > _expr > ')' ) | _serviceCode[ _val = _1 ] );

          _serviceCode = ( +alnum >> "[" >> +alnum >> "]" )
              [ _val = phx::construct<rule<r_sc> >( _1, _2 ) ] |
                  _text;

          _text = qi::lexeme[ +( alnum ) ];
      }
  private:

          qi::rule<It, var() , Skipper> _text;
          qi::rule<It, expr(), Skipper> _not, _and, _xor, _or, _base, _expr, _serviceCode;
  };
  ```

I thought this is it, but this solution does not even compile. the compiler pukes the following error:

> error: parse error in template argument list
>   error: no match for `‘operator>’` in `‘construct<<expression error> > > (boost::spirit::_1, boost::spirit::_2)’`

As I am very new to boost spirit, can somebody please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: just saw the complete typedef for expr got lost:

Comment: typedef boost::variant<
            var,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<unop<op_not> >,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_xor> >,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >,
            boost::recursive_wrapper<rule<r_sc> >
        > expr;

Comment: sorry but i cannot not figure out the difference betweene: _val = phx::construct<rule<r_sc> >( _1, _2 ) and: _val = phx::construct<binop<op_and> >( _1, _2 )? for me they look identical.

Comment: Not sure if that has anything to do with your problem, but you are using `rule` as parameter name in several places. Try using another name.

Comment: As @Henrik notes, the problem lies in a collision between `qi::rule` (with the `using namespace qi` directive) and your own `rule`.

Comment: oh man thx for this hint. staring at template compiler errors made me loose the focus for the problem. renaming the template solved the problem.

Comment: @llonesmiz  I had only a vague idea that some sort of name clash might be the problem. You found the exact cause. Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.