# C++ Boost spirit, multiple evaluations of a same _val?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I tried to modify a boolean expression parser from here : [Boolean expression (grammar) parser in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598)

During the creation of variables, I try to call a new function, "processval". It's just the identity function with some output to see when this function is called. But the thing is, this function is called more than 10 times when I only have 2 variables. Does anybody understand why ?

The code is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a96e1971f9c46cd)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/phoenix/function/adapt_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

struct op_or  {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_xor {};
struct op_not {};

typedef int var;
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;

typedef boost::variant<var, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<unop <op_not> >, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_xor> >,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >
        > expr;

template <typename tag> struct binop 
{ 
    explicit binop(const expr& l, const expr& r) : oper1(l), oper2(r) { }
    expr oper1, oper2; 
};

template <typename tag> struct unop  
{ 
    explicit unop(const expr& o) : oper1(o) { }
    expr oper1; 
};

struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    printer(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}
    std::ostream& _os;

    //
    void operator()(const var& v) const { _os << v; }

    void operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const { print(" & ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }
    void operator()(const binop<op_or >& b) const { print(" | ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }
    void operator()(const binop<op_xor>& b) const { print(" ^ ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }

    void print(const std::string& op, const expr& l, const expr& r) const
    {
        _os << "(";
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, l);
            _os << op;
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, r);
        _os << ")";
    }

    void operator()(const unop<op_not>& u) const
    {
        _os << "(";
            _os << "!";
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, u.oper1);
        _os << ")";
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expr& e)
{ boost::apply_visitor(printer(os), e); return os; }

int processval(int s)
{
    std::cout << "processing val : " << s << std::endl;
    return s;
}

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(int, process_, processval, 1)

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<It, expr(), Skipper>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(expr_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        expr_  = or_.alias();

        or_  = (xor_ >> "or"  >> or_ ) [ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_or >>(_1, _2) ] | xor_   [ _val = _1 ];
        xor_ = (and_ >> "xor" >> xor_) [ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_xor>>(_1, _2) ] | and_   [ _val = _1 ];
        and_ = (not_ >> "and" >> and_) [ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_and>>(_1, _2) ] | not_   [ _val = _1 ];
        not_ = ("not" > simple       ) [ _val = phx::construct<unop <op_not>>(_1)     ] | simple [ _val = _1 ];

        simple = (('(' > expr_ > ')') | var_);
        var_ = int_ [ _val = process_(_1) ];

    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, var() , Skipper> var_;
    qi::rule<It, expr(), Skipper> not_, and_, xor_, or_, simple, expr_;
};

int main()
{
    for (auto& input : std::list<std::string> {
        "1 and 2"
            })
    {
        auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));
        parser<decltype(f)> p;

        try
        {
            expr result;
            bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::space,result);

            if (!ok)
                std::cerr << "invalid input\n";
            else
                std::cout << "result: " << result << "\n";

        } catch (const qi::expectation_failure<decltype(f)>& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "expectation_failure at '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) std::cerr << "unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT :**

The best solution is to change the grammar. See [Bill's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719745/c-boost-spirit-multiple-evaluations-of-a-same-val#comment47575654_29720007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how a parser like spirit works. Let's look at where these calls to `processval()` are happening:

Let's use a simpler grammar to talk about what happens:

```
A = (B >> C) | (B >> B >> C)
B = "B" [ process_(_1) ]
C = "C"
```

Given the input `"BBC"`, we will actually parse `B` three times! This means that any semantic actions like `_process` that we have attached will also be executed three times.

Let's walk the parsing to show why this happens:

1. We start at `A`.
2. The first expression in `A` that we are supposed to try is `B >> C`.
3. The first `B` in that expression parses successfully. So we execute the semantic action.
4. Then we are supposed to follow that `B` with a `C`. This parse fails because the next element in our string is `B`.
5. We then walk up our parse tree until we find that alternative in the `A` rule.
6. Now, we have the option of `A = B >> B >> C`. Let's try this.
7. The first `B` parses successfully. So we call our semantic action for the second time.
8. The second `B` parses successfully. So we call our semantic action for the third time.
9. The `C` parses successfully.
10. That means `A` has parsed successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not understand why when I add outputs in the process, these are called just once : [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb2db980131b6414). And the other question is : in this case, is there any trick to avoid this ? Or should process the parsed result ?

Comment: @waffle: Let's make sure that our cout calls are evaulated lazy! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78df94f0c49f4da4

Comment: @waffle: And to fix it, we need to rewrite our grammar. __Rewrite version 1:__  `or_  = xor_ >> -("or"  >> or_ );` __Rewrite version 2:__ `or_ = xor_ % "or";`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Concerning the rewritings of the grammar, making something like `or_ = xor_ >> -("or" >> or_);` is impossible if we want to create our AST, isn't it ? I do not see how to know if we should go to the "xor level" or if there is already an or operator to parse, and a binop<op_or> to construct in this case ?

Comment: I could also try to create an "empty" unary operator, and then always create binary operators, sometimes with two parameters, and sometimes with one parameter (a xor-based expression) and this empty operator, but it does not look really clean...

Comment: I'm not great at writing semantic actions, but this is what I would do: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a30e11a4f0f13a4a

Comment: Oh thanks. I thought it would create two _val and a big mess when two _val are evaluated in a same subgrammar...

Comment: I'm great at writing semantic actions, and [I still wouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil) :) +1 for explanation here