# Boost::Spirit : Optimizing an expression parser

Tags: c++, parsing, optimization, boost-spirit

I'm trying to write a program to parse and evaluate mathematical, litteral and boolean expressions, for example :

- "(9/3) == 3+3*2" would be parsed as "(9/3) == (3+(3*2))" and evaluted as "false"
- "1+2/3" would be parsed as "1+(2/3)" and evaluated as "6".
- "this + is + a + test" would be parsed as "this+is+a+test" and evaluated as "thisisatest"

The program correctly parses and solves what I'm giving it, but as soon as I put parenthesis in the expressions, the parsing takes a ridiculous amount of time.

I've based my work on [Sehe's impressively exhaustive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c%20%22Sehe's%20impressively%20exhaustive%20exemple%22answer) on how to write a boolean grammar parser. I've added new operators (+, -, /, *, ==, !=) following that example.

Here is the parser

```
    // DEFINING TYPES
struct op_not {};
struct op_or {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_xor {};
struct op_equal {};
struct op_unequal {};
struct op_sum {};
struct op_difference {};
struct op_factor {};
struct op_division {};

typedef ustring var;
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;

typedef boost::variant<var,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<unop <op_not> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_equal> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_unequal> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_xor> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_difference> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_sum> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_factor> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_division> >
> expressionContainer;

template <typename tag> struct binop
{
    explicit binop(const expressionContainer& l
        , const expressionContainer& r)
        : oper1(l), oper2(r) { }
    expressionContainer oper1, oper2;
};

template <typename tag> struct unop
{
    explicit unop(const expressionContainer& o) : oper1(o) { }
    expressionContainer oper1;
};


    // EXPRESSION PARSER
template <typename It, typename Skipper = boost::spirit::standard_wide::space_type>
struct parserExpression : qi::grammar<It, expressionContainer(), Skipper>
{
    parserExpression() : parserExpression::base_type(expr_)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        expr_ = or_.alias();

        // Logical Operators
        or_ = (xor_ >> orOperator_ >> or_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_or >>(_1, _3)]    | xor_[_val = _1];
        xor_ = (and_ >> xorOperator_ >> xor_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_xor>>(_1, _3)]     | and_[_val = _1];
        and_ = (equal_ >> andOperator_ >> and_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_and>>(_1, _3)]   | equal_[_val = _1];
        equal_ = (unequal_ >> equalOperator_ >> equal_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_equal>>(_1, _3)] | unequal_[_val = _1];
        unequal_ = (factor_ >> unequalOperator_ >> unequal_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_unequal>>(_1, _3)] | factor_[_val = _1];

        // Numerical Operators
        factor_ = (division_ >> factorOperator_ >> factor_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_factor>>(_1, _3)] | division_[_val = _1];
        division_ = (sum_ >> divisionOperator_ >> division_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_division>>(_1, _3)] | sum_[_val = _1];
        sum_ = (difference_ >> sumOperator_ >> sum_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_sum>>(_1, _3)] | difference_[_val = _1];
        difference_ = (not_ >> differenceOperator_ >> difference_) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::binop<op_difference>>(_1, _3)] | not_[_val = _1];

        // UNARY OPERATIONS
        not_ = (notOperator_ > simple) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::unop <op_not>>(_2)] | simple[_val = _1];

        simple = (('(' > expr_ > ')') | var_);
        var_ = qi::lexeme[+alnum];

        notOperator_        = qi::char_('!');
        andOperator_        = qi::string("&&");
        orOperator_         = qi::string("||");
        xorOperator_        = qi::char_("^");
        equalOperator_      = qi::string("==");
        unequalOperator_    = qi::string("!=");
        sumOperator_        = qi::char_("+");
        differenceOperator_ = qi::char_("-");
        factorOperator_     = qi::char_("*");
        divisionOperator_   = qi::char_("/");

        /*BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expr_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(or_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(xor_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(and_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(not_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(simple);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(var_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(notOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(andOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(orOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(xorOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(sumOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(differenceOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(factorOperator_);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(divisionOperator_);*/
    }

private:
    qi::rule<It, var(), Skipper> var_;
    qi::rule<It, expressionContainer(), Skipper> not_
        , and_
        , xor_
        , or_
        , equal_
        , unequal_
        , sum_
        , difference_
        , factor_
        , division_
        , simple
        , expr_;

    qi::rule<It, ustring(), Skipper> notOperator_
        , andOperator_
        , orOperator_
        , xorOperator_
        , equalOperator_
        , unequalOperator_
        , sumOperator_
        , differenceOperator_
        , factorOperator_
        , divisionOperator_;
};
```

With the above code, on my computer (running an Intel I5 CPU) :

- parsing "1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5 == 6 != 7 && 8 || 9 ^ 8 * 7 / 6 ^ 5 && 4 || 3 != 2 == 1" is instantaneous.
- parsing "(1)" takes approximately 200ms

Spirit's performance having been proved before, I'm left with the obvious question : what could I improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `(1)` is the worst possible case for backtracking with that grammar. Let's study a simplified example:

```
or_ = (and_ >> '|' >> or_) | and_;
and_ = (not_ >> '&' >> and_) | not_;
not_ = ('!' >> simple_) | simple_;
simple_ = ('(' >> or_ >> ')') | var_;
```

And here is a step by step walkthrough:

- We try `or_`

  - We try `and_`

    - We try `not_`

      - We try `'!'`, `'!' >> simple_` fails
      - We try `simple`

        - We try `'('`, it matches
        - We try `or_`

          - We try `and_`

            - We try `not_`

              - We try `'!'`, `'!' >> simple_` fails
              - We try `simple`

                - We try `'('`, `'(' >> or_ >> ')'` fails
                - We try `var_`, it matches
              - `simple_` suceeds
            - `not_` suceeds
            - We try `'&'`, `not_ >> '&' >> and_` fails (the previous `simple_` and `not_` matches are discarded)
            - We try `not_` (the one that is alone)

              - everything as before
            - `not_` succeeds
          - `and_` succeeds
          - We try `'|'`, `and_ >> '|' >> or_` fails (`and_`, `not_` and `simple_` matches discarded)
          - We try `and_`(the one alone)

            - everything as before
          - `and_` succeeds
        - `or_` succeeds
        - We try `')'`, `'(' >> or_ >> ')'` succeeds
      - `simple_` succeeds
    - `not_` succeeds
    - We try `'&'`, `not_ >> '&' >> and_` fails (everything is discarded)
    - We try `not_` (the one alone)

      - everything as before
    - `not_` suceeds
  - `and_` suceeds
  - We try `'|'`, `and_ >> '|' >> or_` fails (everything is discarded)
  - We try `and_` (the one alone)

    - everything as before
  - `and_` succeeds
- `or_` succeeds

And that is with only two binary rules, your case is much worse.

You could possibly use something like:

```
or_ = and_[_val=_1] >> -( '|' >> or_ )[_val=construct<binop<op_or> >(_val,_1)];
```

and, although even uglier than before, it will not discard any of the matches.

One problem I don't know you if you have noticed is that the result of the parse is right-associative (meaning `3-2-1` => `3-(2-1)`). I think that something like:

```
or_ = and_[_val=_1] >> *( '|' >> and_)[_val=construct<binop<op_or> >(_val,_1)]; //note the `and_` instead of `or_` after '|'
```

could solve the problem, but I haven't tested it.

Also because of the way you have arranged your rules you have given `+` and `-` a higher priority than `*` and `/`.

Trying to solve these problems (and to remove the semantic actions) I have come up with a custom directive that seems to work, you would use it like this:

```
or_ = fold<binop<op_or> >(xor_.alias())['|' >> xor_]; //sadly the `.alias()` is required
```

The directive parses the initial parser (`xor_.alias()`) and tries the subject many times. If the subject never succeeds the final attribute is the attribute of the initial parser. If the subject succeeds the final attribute will be `binop<op_or>(initial_attr,subject_attr)`/`binop<op_or>(binop<op_or>(initial_attr,subject_attr1),subject_attr2)`/...

Full Sample [(Running on WandBox)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zSSKfzlr11SuHoem)

**custom_fold_directive.hpp**

```
namespace custom
{
    namespace tag
    {
        struct fold { BOOST_SPIRIT_IS_TAG() };
    }

    template <typename Exposed, typename Expr>
    boost::spirit::stateful_tag_type<Expr, tag::fold, Exposed>
    fold(Expr const& expr)
    {
        return boost::spirit::stateful_tag_type<Expr, tag::fold, Exposed>(expr);
    }

}

namespace boost { namespace spirit 
{
    template <typename Expr, typename Exposed>
    struct use_directive<qi::domain
          , tag::stateful_tag<Expr, custom::tag::fold, Exposed> >
      : mpl::true_ {};
}}

namespace custom
{
    template <typename Exposed, typename InitialParser, typename RepeatingParser>
    struct fold_directive
    {
        fold_directive(InitialParser const& initial, RepeatingParser const& repeating):initial(initial),repeating(repeating){}

        template <typename Context, typename Iterator>
        struct attribute
        {
            typedef typename boost::spirit::traits::attribute_of<InitialParser,Context,Iterator>::type type;//This works in this case but is not generic
        };

        template <typename Iterator, typename Context
          , typename Skipper, typename Attribute>
        bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
          , Context& context, Skipper const& skipper, Attribute& attr_) const
        {
            Iterator start = first;

            typename boost::spirit::traits::attribute_of<InitialParser,Context,Iterator>::type initial_attr;


            if (!initial.parse(first, last, context, skipper, initial_attr))
            {
                first=start;
                return false;
            }

            typename boost::spirit::traits::attribute_of<RepeatingParser,Context,Iterator>::type repeating_attr;

            if(!repeating.parse(first, last, context, skipper, repeating_attr))
            {
                boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(initial_attr, attr_);
                return true;
            }
            Exposed current_attr(initial_attr,repeating_attr);

            while(repeating.parse(first, last, context, skipper, repeating_attr))
            {
                boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(Exposed(current_attr,repeating_attr),current_attr);
            }
            boost::spirit::traits::assign_to(current_attr,attr_);
            return true;
        }

        template <typename Context>
        boost::spirit::info what(Context& context) const
        {
            return boost::spirit::info("fold");
        }

        InitialParser initial;
        RepeatingParser repeating;
    };
}

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace qi
{
    template <typename Expr, typename Exposed, typename Subject, typename Modifiers>
    struct make_directive<
        tag::stateful_tag<Expr, custom::tag::fold, Exposed>, Subject, Modifiers>
    {
        typedef custom::fold_directive<Exposed, Expr, Subject> result_type;

        template <typename Terminal>
        result_type operator()(Terminal const& term, Subject const& subject, Modifiers const&) const
        {
            typedef tag::stateful_tag<
                Expr, custom::tag::fold, Exposed> tag_type;
            using spirit::detail::get_stateful_data;

            return result_type(get_stateful_data<tag_type>::call(term),subject);
        }
    };
}}}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include "custom_fold_directive.hpp"

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


// DEFINING TYPES
struct op_not {};
struct op_or {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_xor {};
struct op_equal {};
struct op_unequal {};
struct op_sum {};
struct op_difference {};
struct op_factor {};
struct op_division {};

namespace Expression{

typedef std::string var;
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;

typedef boost::variant<var,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<unop <op_not> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_equal> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_unequal> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_xor> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_difference> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_sum> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_factor> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_division> >
> expressionContainer;


template <typename tag> struct binop
{
    explicit binop(const expressionContainer& l
        , const expressionContainer& r)
        : oper1(l), oper2(r) { }
    expressionContainer oper1, oper2;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const binop& val)
    {
        os << "(" << typeid(tag).name() << " " << val.oper1 << ", "<< val.oper2 << ")";
        return os;
    }
};

template <typename tag> struct unop
{
    explicit unop(const expressionContainer& o) : oper1(o) { }
    expressionContainer oper1;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const unop& val)
    {
        os << "(" << typeid(tag).name() << " " << val.oper1 << ")";
        return os;
    }
};

}

    // EXPRESSION PARSER
template <typename It, typename Skipper = boost::spirit::standard_wide::space_type>
struct parserExpression : qi::grammar<It, Expression::expressionContainer(), Skipper>
{
    parserExpression() : parserExpression::base_type(expr_)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        using namespace Expression;
        using custom::fold;

        expr_ = or_.alias();

        // Logical Operators
        or_ = fold<binop<op_or> >(xor_.alias())[orOperator_ >> xor_];
        xor_ = fold<binop<op_xor> >(and_.alias())[xorOperator_ >> and_];
        and_ = fold<binop<op_and> >(equal_.alias())[andOperator_ >> equal_];
        equal_ = fold<binop<op_equal> >(unequal_.alias())[equalOperator_ >> unequal_]; 
        unequal_ = fold<binop<op_unequal> >(sum_.alias())[unequalOperator_ >> sum_];

        // Numerical Operators
        sum_ = fold<binop<op_sum> >(difference_.alias())[sumOperator_ >> difference_];
        difference_ = fold<binop<op_difference> >(factor_.alias())[differenceOperator_ >> factor_];
        factor_ = fold<binop<op_factor> >(division_.alias())[factorOperator_ >> division_]; 
        division_ = fold<binop<op_division> >(not_.alias())[divisionOperator_ >> not_];

        // UNARY OPERATIONS
        not_ = (notOperator_ > simple) [_val = boost::phoenix::construct<Expression::unop <op_not>>(_1)] | simple[_val = _1];

        simple = (('(' > expr_ > ')') | var_);
        var_ = qi::lexeme[+alnum];

        notOperator_        = qi::char_('!');
        andOperator_        = qi::string("&&");
        orOperator_         = qi::string("||");
        xorOperator_        = qi::char_("^");
        equalOperator_      = qi::string("==");
        unequalOperator_    = qi::string("!=");
        sumOperator_        = qi::char_("+");
        differenceOperator_ = qi::char_("-");
        factorOperator_     = qi::char_("*");
        divisionOperator_   = qi::char_("/");

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expr_)(or_)(xor_)(and_)(equal_)(unequal_)(sum_)(difference_)(factor_)(division_)(simple)(notOperator_)
                                 (andOperator_)(orOperator_)(xorOperator_)(equalOperator_)(unequalOperator_)(sumOperator_)(differenceOperator_)(factorOperator_)(divisionOperator_));

    }

private:
    qi::rule<It, Expression::var(), Skipper> var_;
    qi::rule<It, Expression::expressionContainer(), Skipper> not_
        , and_
        , xor_
        , or_
        , equal_
        , unequal_
        , sum_
        , difference_
        , factor_
        , division_
        , simple
        , expr_;

    qi::rule<It, Skipper> notOperator_
        , andOperator_
        , orOperator_
        , xorOperator_
        , equalOperator_
        , unequalOperator_
        , sumOperator_
        , differenceOperator_
        , factorOperator_
        , divisionOperator_;
};

void parse(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin(), end = str.end();

    parserExpression<std::string::const_iterator,qi::space_type> parser;
    Expression::expressionContainer expr;

    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(iter,end,parser,qi::space, expr);

    if(result && iter==end)
    {
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
        std::cout << str << " => " << expr << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    parse("(1)");
    parse("3-2-1");
    parse("a+b*c");
    parse("a*b+c");
    parse("(a+b)*c");
    parse("a*b+c*(d+e)&&true||false");
}
```

Comment: Please tell me you generated that parse tree from the DEBUG "xml" output :)

Comment: That would have been smarter... And more complete.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a bunch for the explanation !